# HP Pavilion dv6700 Notebook WiFi issue

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, hp-pavilion

I have this weird issue with HP Pavilion dv6700 Notebook, running Vista Home Premium.  When a user is trying to get onto WiFi in the office, she sees the network, connects to it, but can't access the Internet (everyone else can).  It's a WAP security enabled network.

I updated the wireless driver, as well as uninstalled the 3rd party WiFi management software.  I am not really sure why it happens.  And she can connect to the WiFi everywhere else, it's just in the office, she can't.

I should also mention, we updated the local hardware firewall and WiFi points.  I tried changing the key, reverting back to the old key (she had a profile saved), removing the profile from her laptop and re-joining to no luck.

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Is there anything like a RADIUS server or another provider managing authentication?

Comment: @DaveM Nope, no RADIUS server nor another provider managing authentication.

Comment: Do ipconfig. Can you ping the gateway? Are you getting DHCPed properly, and are you getting DNS servers?

Comment: try manually setting the ipv4/6 configuration instead of waiting for dhcp

Comment: Like Znau said, hit Start, Run, type cmd to open a command prompt, and then type "ipconfig /all" without quotes, look for the ip address on the WiFi interface, if the IPv4 address starts with 169.xxx.xxx.xxx then DHCP is failing and the computer is assigning itself an IP. You can statically set an IP on the interface, or you can try typing "ipconfig /renew" so hopefully the WiFi interface asks the DHCP server (assuming it is the router) for a new IP address to automatically be assigned.

Comment: @Bigbio2002 Yes, yes, yes

Comment: @Znau Tried that today (sorry for the delay, user was unavailable), didn't work.  Very, very weird, that should have worked...

Comment: @j_bombay It's not 169.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: what is the ip, subnet mask, and gateway?

Comment: @j_bombay It's going to the correct WiFi point as configured in the firewall.

Comment: Are `ping google.com`, `nslookup google.com` and `tracert google.com` successful?

Comment: @grs according to the user, no to all.  If I do the WebEx meeting with her, all are successful, but her laptop at that point is connected to LAN

Comment: It could be the firewall itself, but by some reason, I am doubting that...

Answer (score 0):

I'll be plain but a bit cruel twards HP. I own a DV 6000. This laptop came with Windows XP preinstalled several years ago and after a format the Wifi card NEVER again worked in windows again (tested XP and vista).
Some time after i tested in linux and it worked; i tought it was dead for good. Then, i made a RAM upgrade (from 1GB to 4GB) and tried installing Windows7 trial: i was surprised when the wifi lights were on again and i could access the internet again after hours and days of trying .vbs script files and registry tweaks.

summing things up:
Try adding a partition using windows 7 even if trial. or booting from another drive. Windows probably is the culprit, screwing HP wifi.

Comment: It's a remote user, so I am not sure it would be doable in a near future at least

Comment: good point indeed, now i read the question once again.

Comment: Personally, I would have loved to blow it up and install pro version without any of that add-on soft, but can't...